# Oculus Quest 2 - PC connection

Tags: steam-vr, meta-quest-2

Yesterday I recieved Quest 2 for christmas and I have a few questions.

Can I download steam purchased games on Quest 2 To play wirelessly (for example Beat Saber)?
Can I boost game performance when I connect Quest to my PC while the game is downloaded on Quest? Or does it work only for PC games?

Answer (score 1):

You can not transfer games from Steam onto Quest 2. There are some crossbuy options in Oculus store that give you both Quest 2 versio and PCVR options, but Steam versions can not be brought to Quest 2.

If you want to play BeatSaber with your Quest 2, you have two options:

1. Buy game on Oculus store. This will give you standalone version of the game.
2. Use Oculus Link to play Steam version of the game. You can either use Link cable (any USB 3.1 cable with at least one USB-C connector) or you can use AirLink feature of Oculus software.